# Attempting to map GeoJson file producing issues

Tags: javascript, geojson, d3

I've been trying to get this to work for some time now. The end goal is to produce a map I can show using d3.js, however d3 is butchering the map and producing an undesirable image. The code is as follows:

```
var width  = 1000;
var height = 800;

var vis = d3.select("body").append("svg")
  .attr("width", width).attr("height", height)

d3.json("ca-ns-all.geo.json", function(json) {
// create a first guess for the projection
  var center = d3.geo.centroid(json)
  var scale  = 150;
  var offset = [width/2, height/2];
  var projection = d3.geo.mercator().scale(scale).center(center)
      .translate(offset);

  // create the path
  var path = d3.geo.path().projection(projection);

  // using the path determine the bounds of the current map and use 
  // these to determine better values for the scale and translation
  var bounds  = path.bounds(json);
  var hscale  = scale*width  / (bounds[1][0] - bounds[0][0]);
  var vscale  = scale*height / (bounds[1][1] - bounds[0][1]);
  var scale   = (hscale < vscale) ? hscale : vscale;
  var offset  = [width - (bounds[0][0] + bounds[1][0])/2,
                    height - (bounds[0][1] + bounds[1][1])/2];

  // new projection
  projection = d3.geo.mercator().center(center)
    .scale(scale).translate(offset);
  path = path.projection(projection);

  // add a rectangle to see the bound of the svg
  vis.append("rect").attr('width', width).attr('height', height)
    .style('stroke', 'black').style('fill', 'none');

  vis.selectAll("path").data(json.features).enter().append("path")
    .attr("d", path)
    .style("fill", "red")
    .style("stroke-width", "1")
    .style("stroke", "black")
});
```

And the map is defined from the data below

http://code.highcharts.com/mapdata/countries/ca/ca-ns-all.geo.json

Comment: Can we please see the Nightmare? Will +1 for that image ...

Answer (score 2):

Solved it, the data wasn't WGS84. Thanks everyone!